# Bourbon Refills Navigation JavaScript error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to implement the [horizontal navigation bar](http://refills.bourbon.io/#er-toc-id-12) from bourbon refills site.

Steps I took:

- Copied the html into `/index.php`
- Copied the scss into `/sass/elements/_header.scss`
- Copied the javascript into `/js/header.js`
- Created a `/css/main.css` file
- Created a `/sass/main.sass` file that imports the `/sass/elements/_header.scss` file and compiles it to `/css/main.css`
- no errors detected by Ruby

Then included *.js* files like this (in the correct order)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/header.js"></script>
```

When I open it in Chrome Developer Tools it tells me that the `header.js` file has an error on `line 5`: **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**.

I tried smashing my keyboard and mouse several times to the desk, screaming, hitting my head simultaneously with both hands and looking for the problematic jquery function on line:28 of the googleapis [jquery.min.js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js), but I think it's from the header script.

Comment: can  you please include header.js? It is probably because you have an error somewhere in your script which is preventing the referenced function from being recognized.

Comment: @Wold the `header.js` is copy pasted from [http://refills.bourbon.io/#er-toc-id-12](http://refills.bourbon.io/#er-toc-id-12). I realized that the jquery that I included was an outdated one, so the functions were not compatible. I've posted the answer to the question, but I can't mark it as an answer for 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found

I searched on which is the best site to include jquery from and found the link to the google api site. The link contained version 1.4.3 instead of the newer version (1.11.2), with which it works just fine.